# Запуск php приложения в консольном режиме через http-запрос

Tags: php, shell, консоль

У нас на сайте реализован на php функционал обработки некого функционала, который выполняется примерно 20 мин.

Требуется из обычного php скрипта, который выполняется через веб-сервер, запустить наше приложение на php в консольном (фоновом) режиме, и не дожидаться его выполнения.

Какие есть варианты запуска этого скрипта, и какие у них нюансы?

Сейчас скрипт я запускаю из консоли вручном режиме, вот так: `php -c /path/php.ini script.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

т.е. обычный запуск скрипта с оказанием php.ini который надо юзать и с отвязкой от консоли.

Как можно проделить тоже самое программно ? из php ? Чтобы при возникновении определенных событий в скрипте я мог запустить свое приложение ?

В голову только exec или system приходит..

Comment: Может pcntl поможет ?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать компонент [Symfony Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) -- это хорошая обертка для запуска командной строки из PHP.

Если хочется пойти на более низкий уровень, то под катопом Symfony Process использует функцию [proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php).